# Combining last and first timestamp data of a group data in 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a screenshot table and I want to get the user screenshot time starts and screenshot time ends. I want to create a query to be able to export the data to provide to my users.

Let's say this is my table data.

| scs_id | scs_tracker_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1001 | 2022-02-22 04:00:00 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2022-02-22 01:00:00 |
| 4 | 1002 | 2022-02-22 12:00:00 |
| 5 | 1001 | 2022-02-22 08:00:00 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2022-02-22 02:00:00 |

My expected output should be:

| scs_tracker_id | screenshot_starts | screenshot_ends |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 | 2022-02-22 02:00:00 |
| 1001 | 2022-02-22 04:00:00 | 2022-02-22 08:00:00 |
| 1002 | 2022-02-22 12:00:00 | 2022-02-22 12:00:00 |

Code that I'm playing as of the moment:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM screen_shots GROUP BY scs_tracker_id ORDER BY scs_id ASC LIMIT 1) AS screenshot_starts,
(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM screen_shots GROUP BY scs_tracker_id ORDER BY scs_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS screenshot_ends
FROM screen_shots
```

Comment: could you edit your question to add (as text, not an image) output of `show create table screen_shots` and `select version()`?

Comment: what defines what is first and last?  is it just the earliest and latest created_at times?  or the least and greatest scs_id?

Comment: @ysth the basis is either created_at or scs_id. Solution from Tim works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by tracker ID and then take the min/max timestamp:

```
SELECT
    scs_tracker_id,
    MIN(created_at) AS screenshot_starts,
    MAX(created_at) AS screenshot_ends
FROM screen_shots
GROUP BY scs_tracker_id;
```